# ad users filtered by 'city' and 'member of' group using powershell

Tags: powershell

We are starting to upgrade our Citrix platform and I am trying to use AD to get a list of users currently at specific sites and who use our Citrix environment.
I currently have the following to filter the site and remove any leavers etc:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'City -Like "Portsmouth" -and Description -notlike "LEAVER*" -and Description -notlike "This user was*"' | select-object name, userprincipalname | format-table
```

This works great, however I now need to filter by people only in our Citrix 'Member of' group.
I believe I can use the following on its own:

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'Citrix_USR'
```

However I am struggling to find a way to add this into my earlier search and get it working.
Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be great.

P.S this is my first time posting, please take it easy on me, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform filtering with `Where-Object` cmdlet for **MemberOf** property.

Make sure you specify requested properties with `Get-ADUser` cmdlet `-Properties MemberOf` or `-Properties *`

Like so:

```
#first you get distinguished name
$dn = Get-ADGroup 'Citrix_USR' | Select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
#now you perform filtering
Get-ADUser -Filter 'City -Like "Portsmouth" -and Description -notlike "LEAVER*" -and Description -notlike "This user was*"' -Properties MemberOf | Where-Object {$_.MemberOf.Contains($dn)} | Select-Object name, userprincipalname | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect!